# What is the correct way to define entities in the datastore when dealing with mass data?

Tags: java, android, database, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm making an instant messaging app for android and using Java and app engine for the backend.

To store conversations and messages in the backend, I have 2 options (as I see it) to store the data.

Create 2 root entities:
 conversation (ID, message IDs) and message (ID, "text").

OR

conversation(ID) message (child of conversation entity)(ID, "text")

Though technically both can work, I do not understand about the limits of the datastore (ex 1 write/sec for some entities), am worried about CPU overhead when querying, as well as having potentially millions of message root entries. I guess I am not sure if ancestral entities are required, or best for such an application.

tl;dr what is the best way to architect such a database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use ancestors queries Unless you are sure they fit your needs. this was to me the most confusing part about datastore because at first, parent/child seems like a great way to structure data like a tree.
In short, use them when you must have inmediate consistency when you write data. It has sevetal restrictions regarding total size and writes per second.

dont worry about having millions of "root" entities. This is precisely what the datastore (and nosql in general) is good about.
all datastore queries are efficient, it wont even let you run one that it isnt (so you must add all needed indexes beforehand) thus dont worry about query performance unless you cant express the query with an index.
in your case, given that a conversation shouldnt be huge and users normally dont type more than 5 entries per second, you could use ancestors and you will gain inmediate consistency within each conversation.
At this point i think its too broad to ask for the arquitecture but this should point you the right way.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking/worried about. Thank you for confirming it so clearly for me.

Comment: You edit has confused me. i thought that the data stoer will only allow 1 write/sec in the acestral structure. so in a group conversation where many people could send messages quickly, it would be limited. 

I guess if there are limitations to the structure and write speed, why wouldnt I just make all kinds in the root?

Comment: But each unique conversation is between two people right? They wont write so quickly and if they do on bursts you can handle it with exponential backoff

Comment: Sorry i changed my answer. I later realized your case could indeed make good use of ancestors. If they fit by all means use them.

Comment: Well, it is my frist time using the datastore, so I'm not sure if they fit.

to answer your question, a "conversation" could be 1on1, or up to 10 people in a large group chat. Also, there is the possibility of media (pictures, stickers) etc being added to the score. these would all become elements inside the "conversation"

Comment: The images would be elsewhere. Only their links go in datastore. If 10 people chat at the same time constantly (not just bursts) then you cant use ancestors. But if you dont need the consistency dont use them and deal with eventual consistency (more work)

Comment: If you are doing a chat app then you are already pushing the conversation to each client as the chat happens thus clients dont need to query the server for the convo with realtime consistency. Thus i dont see why you need the consistency that ancestors give. If so we are back to my original answer which said not to use them. The swing in the answer really reflects how much the deails in the use case for datastore determines if ancestors should be used.

Comment: totally agree. the history (database) would be upon refresh, or wake up. not the main means of messaging.

More like if a user lost their phone, their chat history would be saved. again, thanks for the great answers

Comment: Update: Data store limitations will not make it a usable DB for large scale data. A solution like Magellan and MQTT must be implemented. However, for a quick prototype, both approaches above can be employed.

Comment: which limitations are you refering to? if you dont use ancestors it will be fine.